# Aplicar força clicando e arrastando unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom dia, sou iniciante no unity então desculpem se eu falar besteira haha

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo onde preciso colocar uma bola em um cesto, o que não estou conseguindo fazer é clicar e arrastar na bola pra aplicar a força e nem mudar a intensidade dá força de acordo com a distância entre o ponto em que se clica e o que se solta o nosso do mouse. Alguém sabe como?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. O que vc já tentou? Edite a pergunta e poste o código que já tem, para que possamos ajudá-lo com ele. Enquanto isso, faça o [tour] e leia [ask].

Comment: Sim, alguém sabe como. Mas existem mil formas de fazer. O que você já tentou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que criar procedimentos que tratem um evento de entrada, como por exemplo o ato de "clicar e arrastar o mouse" (você tem que estudar a API da Unity). Os procedimentos se resumem em dizer o que vai acontecer ao se clicar e arrastar o mouse.

Você pode incrementar um campo tantas unidades requeridas "por frame" (melhor "por segundo" - aprenda sobre como implementar apartir de `Time.deltaTime`).

Você pode decidir que um deslize no mouse no eixo x negativo deve incrementar o campo e no eixo x positivo o inverso. O valor do campo no momento em se que soltar o botão do mouse é o que vai determinar a quantidade de força ao qual você deve dar sentido e direção por meio um objeto da classe `Vector3` (para isso você tem que usar as bibliotecas de física do Unity).